# 45 sec slow run of Spring boot using JPA and Postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am encountring a problem of very slow running for Spring Boot application using different IDEs (Eclipse, Intellij).
My configurations is: 
jdk 1.8; Postgres 10;

And it sticks in here for like 40 seconds before finishing and activating the server.

```
2018-05-12 23:02:59.239  INFO 16316 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@169dcc51
```

This happened recently after a while. Any solutions?

Comment: Did you change something? Modified your config?

Comment: Probably configuration issue

Comment: @YassinHajaj, no! Any idea how to reinitialise the configuration?

Comment: @GasmiAdel Not a clue sorry. But you first have to check what changed. Are you versioning your app?